# Что лучше использовать flutter или xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, flutter

Есть задание разработать приложение для универа, при этом чтоб оно было доступно как для iOS так и для Android. Разрабатывать отдельно возможности нету, до этого работал с языками Java и Python. Подскажите что проще в освоении и что посоветуете? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

**За Flutter:**

1. Dart будет легче в освоении во много раз, чем C# (и .NET + Mono).
2. Декларативное построение UI позволяет быстрее разрабатывать
   интерфейс приложения.
3. Легко делать сложный UI.
4. HotReload & HotRestart, позволяют разрабатывать в реальном времени (видеть все изменения на лету).
5. Чтобы начать разрабатывать достаточно скачать плагин для IntelliJ IDEA или VSCode и сам движок (размером 800 мб). Для Xamarin вам придется скачать порядка 20-30гб.
6. Хорошая документация со множественными примерами.
7. Легко тестировать приложение.

**За Xamarin:**

1. Маленький размер приложения при релизе.
2. Документация на русском языке.
3. Огромное комьюнити, на большинство вопросов уже есть ответы.
4. Много примеров от комьюнити.

---

Чтобы решить что лучше для вас, необходимо попробовать обе технологии и выбрать ту на которой вам удобнее и приятнее разрабатывать. Если у вас нет времени чтобы попробовать их, то выбирайте Flutter не прогадаете!

Answer (score 2):

В ответе склоняюсь к Flutter так как разработка на нем намного более комфортная и за счет HotReload & HotRestart более быстрая и динамичная.

Работать с Flutter можно практически на любом железе. В свою очередь Xamarin требует приличной мощности только чтобы запуститься.
Flutter - динамично развивается и вскоре обретет соразмерное комьюнити. Ну и как следствие Русскую документацию.

---

> Выше представлено лично мое мнение, и мои наблюдения. Работал и на Flutter и на Xamarin для Android и не только. В итоге выбор всегда остается за вами. Всегда первую очередь думайте своей головой.